Проблемы при записи данных из телеграмм бота в БД mySql
Создала бота с помощью telebot и пытаюсь записать полученные данные в БД
Но вместо фамилии, имени и отчества в БД попадают пустые значения
 elif call.data == 'yes':
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = '''insert into client(FirstName, LastName, Patronymic, Phone)
        values (%s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        values = (userdata[0], userdata[1], userdata[2], user_data.get('phone', ''))
        cursor.execute(sql, values)

def get_surname(message):
    user_data['surname'] = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите Военный комиссариат")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_vk)
    name_parts = user_data['surname'].split()
    if len(name_parts) == 3:
        surname = name_parts[0]
        name = name_parts[1]
        patronymic = name_parts[2]
    return surname, name, patronymic
    userdata = (surname, name, patronymic)


У вас не срабатывает условие if len(name_parts) == 3, и поэтому переменная surname "не появляется" при выполнении. Выход из положения, в начале функции инициализировать surname:
def get_surname(message):
    surname = ""
    ...

